# React.js: How to compare data from 2 objects of arrays?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of objects displayed on the UI. Now I want to change the style of the data which doesn't match with the data from another array of objects. 
Basically my goal is to create a boolean data which checks if the data are matching for both array of objects, and according to this boolean data the style will be changed.
Here is what I have. 
And [codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-mayer-o1z4f?file=/src/App.js)

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const result1 = [
  { id: 1, name: "Sandra", type: "user", username: "sandra" },
  { id: 2, name: "John", type: "admin", username: "johnny2" },
  { id: 3, name: "Peter", type: "user", username: "pete" },
  { id: 4, name: "Bobby", type: "user", username: "be_bob" },
  { id: 5, name: "Bob", type: "user", username: "bob" },
  { id: 6, name: "James", type: "user", username: "james" },
  { id: 7, name: "Bill", type: "user", username: "bill" }
];

const result2 = [
  { id: 2, name: "John", username: "johnny2" },
  { id: 5, name: "Bob", type: "user", username: "bob" },
  { id: 4, name: "Bobby", username: "be_bob" }
];

export default function App() {
  const excludedPerson = result1.filter(
    (person1) => !result2.some((person2) => person1.name === person2.name)
  );

  console.log(excludedPerson);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {result1.map((person) => (
        <ul key={person.id}>
          <div>{person.name}</div>
          <div
            style={{
              textDecoration: "boolean" ? "line-through" : "none" // instead of string it should be a  boolean
            }}
          >
            {person.username}
          </div>
        </ul>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `filter` you can use `map` and get the boolean `excludedPerson` array

**changes:**

**1)** use map instead of filter

```
const excludedPerson = result1.map(
  (person1) => !result2.some((person2) => person1.name === person2.name)
);
```

**2)** Add second parameter in JSX i.e `index`

```
  {result1.map((person, i) => (
```

**3)** change CSS styles accordingly: I've strike through the `result1` elements that are not in `result2`

```
textDecoration: !excludedPerson[i] ? "line-through" : "none"
```

[CODE DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-fog-pd8fk?file=/src/App.js)

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const result1 = [
  { id: 1, name: "Sandra", type: "user", username: "sandra" },
  { id: 2, name: "John", type: "admin", username: "johnny2" },
  { id: 3, name: "Peter", type: "user", username: "pete" },
  { id: 4, name: "Bobby", type: "user", username: "be_bob" },
  { id: 5, name: "Bob", type: "user", username: "bob" },
  { id: 6, name: "James", type: "user", username: "james" },
  { id: 7, name: "Bill", type: "user", username: "bill" }
];

const result2 = [
  { id: 2, name: "John", username: "johnny2" },
  { id: 5, name: "Bob", type: "user", username: "bob" },
  { id: 4, name: "Bobby", username: "be_bob" }
];

export default function App() {
  const excludedPerson = result1.map(
    (person1) => !result2.some((person2) => person1.name === person2.name)
  );

  console.log(excludedPerson);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {result1.map((person, i) => (
        <ul key={person.id}>
          <div>{person.name}</div>
          <div
            style={{
              textDecoration: !excludedPerson[i] ? "line-through" : "none" // instead of string it should be a  boolean
            }}
          >
            {person.username}
          </div>
        </ul>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hi @decpk thanks for the answer. That is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Mabye something like this? Return only the common objects in the two array of objects

```js
const result1 = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Sandra', type: 'user', username: 'sandra' },
  { id: 2, name: 'John', type: 'admin', username: 'johnny2' },
  { id: 3, name: 'Peter', type: 'user', username: 'pete' },
  { id: 5, name: 'Bob', type: 'user', username: 'bob' },
  { id: 6, name: 'James', type: 'user', username: 'james' },
  { id: 7, name: 'Bill', type: 'user', username: 'bill' },
];

const result2 = [
  { id: 2, name: 'John', username: 'johnny2' },
  { id: 5, name: 'Bob', type: 'user', username: 'bob' },
  { id: 4, name: 'Bobby', username: 'be_bob' },
];

const output = result1.filter(({ id: id1 }) =>
  result2.some(({ id: id2 }) => id2 === id1)
);

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Hi @RootAtKali thanks for the answer. 
Actually, I don't want to change the data on the UI, I want only to change style. 'decpk' already gave a correct answer. Thanks again for the answer